# C++ char or logical operator? Why takes else{...} if correct?

Tags: c++

```
        #include <iostream>

                int main()
                {
                    char username[15];
                    char password[15];


                    std::cout << "Hello, please login to continue your action.<Max 15 Char>" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "Username: ";
                    std::cin >> username;
                    std::cout << "Password: ";
                    std::cin >> password;

                    if (username == "User" && password == "qwerty")
                    {
                        std::cout << "Hello, creator.";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        std::cout << "Invalid Login";
                    }
/*23 row*/          std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "Username=" <<username << std::endl << "Password=" << password;

                    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "Press Enter to close the window . . . ";
                    std::cin.clear();
                    std::cin.sync();
                    std::cin.get();
                }
```

When i type correct it should say Hello Creator but it only goes to invalid i thinked maybe char stores only 1 char thats why at 23 row i taked look what is stored in char username and pasword but everything is fine. Why then it takes Else {...} sentence?

Comment: Use std::string for string comparisation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two types of strings in C++. The kind you are using for `username` and `password` are [old-style C strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte). They are basically a sequence of characters in memory, terminated by a special character `'\0'`. Since they come from old C, you can not use things like comparison or assignment operators on them.

To compare two old-style C string you have to use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) function:

```
if (strcmp(username, "user") == 0)
{
    // username == "user"
}
```

A better solution is to use the new C++ string class: [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead, as it has lot more functionality built in. For example handling comparison.

Comment: And as usual, by "new C++ string class" you actually mean the "more than 10 years old C++ string class."

Answer (score 1):

Strcmp is ok when you code in c. It's greatly recommended that you use string in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string username;                
  std::string password;                                                                                                                                                               
  std::cout << "Hello, please login to continue your action.<Max 15 Char>" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Username: ";

  std::cin >> username;
  std::cout << "Password: ";
  std::cin >> password;

  if (username == "User" && password == "qwerty")
     {
      std::cout << "Hello, creator.";
     }
  else 
    {
      std::cout << "Invalid Login";
     }
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "Username=" <<username << std::endl << "Password=" << password;

  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "Press Enter to close the window . . . ";
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.sync();
  std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to compare `char[]` with a `char*`.  This is doing a pointer comparison instead of a string comparison and hence you're getting a false because they are a different pointer address.  Use `std::string` for `username` and `password` and then you'll get a comparison you're expecting

```
std::string username;
std::string password;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in the comparison.  To compare character arrays, you need to use a function like strcmp to compare the contents of character arrays.   If I recall correctly, I believe you are comparing pointers, not the contents of the character array, one of which is the item in quotes (such as "User" or "Qwerty").

I would suggest using std:string which is designed to use the == (as an operator) for the comparing the items and I think you will find it works much better and is easier to use for strings information.